# Converting a FetchAPI to a table

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following function that provides a JSON in the console. I have trouble on displaying that JSON as a table on a webpage.

```
function fetch = () =>
const url = '';
fetch(url).then(response) => {
console.log(response);
})
.catch((e)) => {
console.log(e);
});
}
```

The JSON is similar to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1WkS.png
I need to fill out the return function of the table in typescript. How do I do that using the map function as well as the fetch function? Please use the example to show the return.

```
return (
<>

</>
);
}
```

Comment: Is this expected in React?

Comment: @subodhkalika It is expected in React Typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the response.playlists array and display a row for each song object.

To display the table you might not have to worry about the typescript.

```js
const [playLists, setPlayLists] = useState([]);   // Create a state variable for playlists


function fetch = () =>
  const url = '';
  fetch(url)
  .then(response) => {
    setPlayLists(response.playlists);   // set the state playlists
  })
  .catch((e)) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
return (
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Song ID</th>
      <th>Upvotes</th>
    </tr>
   {
    playLists && playLists.map(song => {  // Loop through the playLists
      return <tr>
        <td>{song.name}</td>
        <td>{song.songID}</td>
        <td>{song.upvotes}</td>
      </tr>
    })
   }
  </table>
 );
```

> TYPESCRIPT SOLUTION:

```js
import * as React from "react";

const baseURL = "https://api.***.com";
const getPlaylistUrl = `${baseURL}/songsList`;
export interface Song {
  name: string;
  songID: string;
  upvotes: number;
}

const getPlaylist = (): Promise<Song[]> => {
  const promise = new Promise<Song[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      Axios.get<Song[]>(getPlaylistUrl).then(response =>
        resolve(mapMemberListApiToModel(response))
      );
    } catch (ex) {
      reject(ex);
    }
  });

  return promise;
};

const mapMemberListApiToModel = ({
  data
}: AxiosResponse<any[]>): Song[] =>
  data.map(song => ({
    name: song.name,
    songID: song.songID,
    upvotes: song.upvotes
}));


const usePlaylist = () => {
  const [playList, setPlayList] = React.useState<
  Song[]
  >([]);

  const loadPlayLists = async () => {
    const playListData = await getPlaylist();
    setPlayList(playListData);
  };

  return { playList, loadPlayLists };
};

export const SongTableComponent = () => {
  const { playList, loadPlayLists } = usePlaylist();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadPlayLists();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Avatar</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {playList.map((song) => (
            <SongRow key={song.songID} song={song} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

const SongRow = ({ song }: { song: Song }) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{song.name}</td>
    <td>{song.songID}</td>
    <td>{song.upvotes}</td>
  </tr>
);
```

Comment: Hi @subodhkalika. Thank you so much for the solution! However, I will need it in typescript instead of reactjs. Is it possible if you can do that?

Comment: @PriyaVarun I have added a typescript solution.

Comment: Hi @subodhkalika. Thank you so much! I was just wondering, can we use the fetch code to display the data dynamically through typescript or is that not possible?